# Can we read specific addresses on the flash memory of an STM32F407 Discovery microcontroller in Level 1 Read-Out Protection Mode?

Tags: stm32f4discovery

Can we read specific addresses on Flash Memory of an STM32F407 microcontroller in Level 1 Read-Out Protection Mode?

Best

Answer (score 0):

According to User Manual of the corresponding microcontroller, no we cannot read.